# How to use getPage() on a request with a request body?

Tags: java, error-handling, http-post, htmlunit

At work, I am using HtmlUnit version 2.8, and I've come to this kafkaian situation:

I have a `WebRequest` that has a body, thus no request parameters: using `WebRequest.setRequestParameters()` when the request body is not `null` throws a:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Trying to set the request parameters, but the request body has already been specified;the two are mutually exclusive!
```

(source available [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit/2.8/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebRequest.java#270))

However, when I use `webClient.getPage(webRequest)`, I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: parameters
```

(source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit/2.8/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.java#1346))

That really verbose message meaning that it's not OK to have `null` for request parameters.

Is there a way to fix this, or bypass it? Preferably using same version (again, 2.8), as I don't have the rights to do upgrade the frameworks we use.

Comment: that moment when you have to choose between a NullPointerException or a RuntimException... Such dilemma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the default constructor initializes by default the request's parameters to `Collections.emptyList()`, so it will not cause the NullPointerException.

What *did* cause my exception though, was that a few lines before I called

```
request.setRequestParameters(null);
```

which obviously was the cause to my issue.

I removed that line and now it works just as expected.